# To copy text from excel to word as sentence without cell borders

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have an excel with a specific column having text in multiple lines within each cells. I want to copy that multi-line text into word document as sentence in word format. I tried several codes but all that copies the excel range and pastes in word exactly the same way it is in excel including the cell borders. I do not want cell borders. I want text to be copied as a sentence/paragraph. Can someone please help me with this.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document

Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application.8")
wApp.Visible = True
Const strPath1 As String = "D:\Template.docx"
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add(Template:=strPath1, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Copy

With wDoc.Paragraphs(wDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
         .Paste
End With

ErrorHandler:
        Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: For future reference, this is **not** vbscript - this is VBA. I've added the correct tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use copy and paste, you need to use the Excel VBA object model to reference the cell you want and then access the text using cell.Value.

You must already be using Excel.Application, and you must already be referencing the cell since you copy and paste the value, so swap the code you have to copy and paste with the code to use the cell.value.

Unfortunately, I'm not at my computer so I can't test this, but you want to replace your code with something like

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document

Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application.8")
wApp.Visible = True
Const strPath1 As String = "D:\Template.docx"
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add(Template:=strPath1, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

Dim currentcell as variant
Dim result as string

For each currentcell in Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))

    Result =result & currentcell.value & vbcrlf

Next currentcell

With wDoc.Paragraphs(wDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
         .Text= result
End With

ErrorHandler:
        Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm new to macro, especially to object methods. So could you please help me with the code ?

Comment: Add your current code to your question. There isn't enough information to help you at the moment!

Comment: I used the below code. Basically, I trying to select a column range from an excel and trying to paste it into a word document.

Comment: Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document

Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application.8")
wApp.Visible = True
Const strPath1 As String = "D:\Template.docx"
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add(Template:=strPath1, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

Worksheets("Sheet2").ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Copy

With wDoc.Paragraphs(wDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
          'All formatting goes here
       .Paste
End With

ErrorHandler:
  ' Insert code to handle the error here
  Resume Next

End Sub

Comment: Can you put the code in your question, and format it please ... You need to insert 4 spaces before each line of code!

Comment: I'm not being awkward, but if you don't follow the rules of the website, people will not be keen to help you!!

Comment: Hi. I tried running your code but i'm getting 'Compiler error- Method or Data member not found', highlighting .Value (where we are trying to paste the value into  word document within wDoc.Paragraphs(wDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range

Comment: Could you please help me fixing 'Compiler error- Method or Data member not found' when .value is used in the above code that you added.

Comment: Just edited. You should use .Text instead of .Value!

Comment: Magic!! Its working. Thank you:) Is there any way where I can remove the line breaks in each cell?

Comment: Good to hear! Yes you can remove this bit as it represents a new line between each item ... & vbcrlf